# How to add Core Data to Static Framework for iOS?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios, applet

I develop Static Library in XCode. I want to use Core Data by using Core Data model (file with extension .xcdatamodeld).

When I want to add it to project, it's impossible to check in "Get info" field, so it'll be used in this framework.

How should I add such data, so framework will be able to use it.

Thanks and take care plp :)

Answer (score 1):

You add Core Data as a Framework to get access to its headers, like you would with any other (application) project. Your users will then also need to add it as a Framework when they build their apps.

You can't and shouldn't add Core Data statically, if you're thinking of it.

Comment: Yes, I would add that it is up to the project for the executable linking to your static library to link to the framework your static library depends upon.  E.g., the app needs to link to the framework.  That's how it'll pick up those symbols at runtime.